# Prove that $a_n=\{\cos(n\pi)\}$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $a_n=\{\cos(n\pi)\}$ diverges?

It is quite obvious since it always is periodic between $1$ and $-1$, but how do I show this?

I learned to do this by contradiction.

**Pf.**

Assume $a_n=\{\cos(n\pi)\}$ converges to some $L \in \mathbb{R}$
I want to show that:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0, s.t, n>N \to |\cos(n\pi)-L| < \epsilon$

Now what I would do is consider $two$ cases, when $n$ is $even$, and when it is $odd$. But I don't see how that would be of use here?

Comment: Hint: if a sequence converges then any subsequence converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $L$, let $\epsilon=1$, and any $N>0$, you have:

$$|a_{2N}-L|+|a_{2N+1}-L|\geq |a_{2N}-a_{2N+1}|=2.$$

So it is not possible for $|a_{2N}-L|<\epsilon$ and $|a_{2N+1}-L|<\epsilon$.